# Determining Variables in a Arraylist of Characters Java

Tags: java, arraylist, boolean-logic

Hi I have a arraylist of characters where i stored my logic expression. My code count the variables in the list and my problem is when I have same variable but there is a not sign and also a parenthesis. For example: xy+zy' the number of variables should be 4 the y and y' are different.

```
public void simplify(String strexp){

 int length = strexp.length();

     //get the size and variables used in expression
    List<Character> usedVariables = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = strexp.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c) && !usedVariables.contains(c)&&usedVariables.contains('\'')) {
            usedVariables.add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your variables may be longer than one character, you should consider an array list of Strings, not chars.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to redesign your code using this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-z]'?").matcher(strExpr);
while (m.find()) {
    String var = m.group();
    ...
}
```

Comment: how about if my expression has a parenthesis?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not totally clear to me what you want to do. Simple expression parsing/interpretation can use a stack, pushing on `(` and popping on `)`.

Comment: I am going to make a truth table and first i need to identify the variables used in the expression. The 2 outputs of the truth table come from the unsimplified expression and the simplified expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple possible solution to your problem

```
public static void simplify(String strexp){

         int length = strexp.length();

             //get the size and variables used in expression
            java.util.List<String> usedVariables = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                String c = strexp.charAt(i) + "";       

                  // check for character which are not actual


                if (!usedVariables.contains(c)) {
                    usedVariables.add(c);
                }else{
                    if((i+1) < length){
                        String c2 = strexp.charAt(i+1) + "";

                        if(c2.equals("'")){
                            c = c + c2;
                            if (!usedVariables.contains(c)) {
                                usedVariables.add(c);
                            }
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            }
            System.out.println(""+usedVariables.size());
        }
```